# Raspberry pi 4 - wi-fi only works after dhcpcd restart - related to docker networks on same pi?

Tags: wifi, docker

I'm having issues with wi-fi on my raspberry pi 4. It doesn't work on start up and I see the message "No wireless interfaces found" - ethernet is working fine at this point.

When I run `sudo systemctl restart dhcpcd` the interfaces restart and both work ok.

I'm running a number of docker containers on this pi and the show "veth" entries when I run `ifconfig`. I'm not sure if this is related.

Grateful for any advice on how to fix the wifi. It's not really practical to have this pi connected to ethernet all the time.

```
pi@rpi4-2:~ $ ifconfig
br-2b0a7f8bfa05: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.30.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.30.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:f9ff:fe40:84e1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:f9:40:84:e1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 257  bytes 19908 (19.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 476  bytes 127526 (124.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

br-5ecf753f05e4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.19.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.19.255.255
        inet6 fe80::42:7dff:fee2:e8d6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 02:42:7d:e2:e8:d6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 245  bytes 88764 (86.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:dd:c8:b3:8e  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.2.143  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.2.255
        inet6 fe80::4361:e091:e34e:8513  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:51:9e:f9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3234  bytes 2039920 (1.9 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 6  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2488  bytes 541633 (528.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 831  bytes 231732 (226.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 831  bytes 231732 (226.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth014307e: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::7841:baff:fe64:9a5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 7a:41:ba:64:09:a5  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 34  bytes 45844 (44.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 314  bytes 112673 (110.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

veth33b4f26: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::2ce6:59ff:fe0a:5d30  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 2e:e6:59:0a:5d:30  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 26  bytes 1700 (1.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 305  bytes 111572 (108.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: We need more info - where does the "No wireless interfaces found" message come from? Show the output of "ifconfig -a", as this will also report on DOWN interfaces. After a reboot, what is the output of "journalctl -u dhcpcd"? How have you configured eth0? Is it obtaining its address through DHCP?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a workaround but no fix.

I use a cronjob which starts a script every minute. The script checks if it can ping my router. If there is no 192.168.1.1 it starts sudo dhcpcd.

Do not do any manual configuration to dhcpcd.conf or interfaces. I made the IPs (eth0 & wlan0) static by the router settings.

Comment: https://weworkweplay.com/play/rebooting-the-raspberry-pi-when-it-loses-wireless-connection-wifi/

I used this script. Just changed the reboot line to "sudo dhcpcd"